# setEmptyText for list in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I am developing a sencha app. I have 'emptyText' set for list in its config. But after some time i need to change it. I used following line to do that

```
invoiceList.setEmptyText('<div style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: center">Sorry! No Items Found</div>');
```

when i run my app in crome, i see following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setEmptyText'

How can i change emptyText for list dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Ext.List has not method setEmptyText in the sencha touch 1. You can use instead sencha touch 2. 
Maybe this code will be work in sencha touch 1. You can try.

```
invoiceList.emptyText = 'Empty test'
invoiceList.refresh();
```